# Rhomobile Building for Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile, rhomobile, rhodes

How can I make Rhomobile build in Windows Mobile 6.5?

I have the Windows Mobile 6.5 DTK and the emulators show up in the device emulator manager.

What do I put in the build.yml of the project:
  wm:
  sdk: Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK (ARMV4I)
  emulator: Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional VGA Emulator

And I get the error:

```
vcbuild.exe : error VCBLD0007: Could not find project configuration RELEASE|WINDOWS MOBILE 6.5.3 PROFESSIONAL DTK (ARMV4I) to build.

No such file or directory - C:/RhoStudio/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rhodes-3.3.2/platform/wm/bin/Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK (ARMV4I)/rhodes/Release/rhodes.exe
```

Am I missing something? This sounds stupid, but how do I get the Windows Mobile 6.5.3 files into Rhostudio, as I do not remember doing anything special for Windows Mobile 6?

Again sorry if this is a stupid question, I just really can't get my head around it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rhomobile have a quite detailed guide to how you need to set up Rhodes for Windows Mobile [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/build#build-for-windows-mobile). To me it sounds like you may have forgotten to run the `rhodes-setup` command to set the paths correctly in your rhobuild.yml file (not your project build.yml, but the one located in your rhodes directory).

The documentation states that it should look something like this:

```
env:
   paths:
     vcbuild: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 8/VC/vcpackages/vcbuild.exe
     cabwiz: C:/Program Files/Windows Mobile 6 SDK/Tools/CabWiz
```

There are some cases (for instance if you are using Visual Studio 2010) where the settings might be different. It may also be useful to look at [this section](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/build#build-for-windows) and add the paths to your `PATH` environment variable.

If none of these things help I would recommend you to download the latest version of their master branch [here on GitHub](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes) since I know that there was a problem with building for Windows Mobile not so long ago, which have been fixed. According to my memory, it is scheduled to be released in version 3.3.3 of Rhodes.

Answer (score 0):

I did face this issue and able to resolve this Problem by pointing to Right vcbuild.exe. I found vcbuild.exe coming with Express Editions doesn't work but then I target to VCBuild.exe of (Visual Studio Team System 2008 which exists in Folder Microsoft Visual Studio 2009 instead of 2008) it worked.

I guess you know it already but then also just to Add:

You have to set  VS build tool path @ RhoStudio -. Windo ->Preferences ->RhoMobile ->Windows Mobile.

Hope it helps

Thanks
Sumeet

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall WM6 SDK, take Professional version, unblock the MSI file and install under administrator privileges (the simplest way is to run cmd as Administrator)

This worked for me.